# Hydrolysis of benzalchloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What should be the mechanism for hydrolysis of benzalchloride to benzaldehyde? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here

B denotes Brønsted base
and HA denotes acid

[image]

Comment: What is the product of second step C6H5CCl ? The valency of C is not satisfied.

Comment: Its a carbene sort of a structure

Comment: How carbon gets double bonded oxygen in last step?

Comment: check the answer now

Comment: Where goes the proton of water in first step of second picture?

Comment: It doesnt matter ,its there somewhere in the solution

Comment: Could you please add a little bit clear pic?

Comment: sure will do after sometime

Comment: I don’t believe this unless you back it with a mechanism-researching paper.

Comment: @Jan is that wrong?

Comment: No it isnt.
It is based on research work    .


THE MECHANISM OF THE HYDROLYSIS
OF BENZAL CHLORIDE
By
Kozo TANABE and Tadaatsu 100*)
(Received December 20, 1964)

Comment: @PrakharSankrityayan That’s not even a citation. Citations include authors (first names abbreviated to initials), Journal, year, potentially volume and page number.